# Automatically invoking FB.login on Facebook page tab app for non-logged in user

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-oauth

I have a Facebook Page tab app. For a user who is not logged in, I want to:

- Detect if user is not logged in
- If not logged in, automatically direct user to login

My current approach is to use FB Javascript SDK (in preference to server-side authentication flow):

- On page load, run `FB.getLoginStatus` to check user status
- If user is not logged in, run `FB.login` to invoke OAuth dialog

Problem:

- `FB.login` creates a pop-up dialog (prefer if within Page Tab iframe)
- This pop-up dialog is blocked if `FB.login` is not invoked from a button (I would really like to avoid having the user click a button; so would really like to invoke it automatically, when I find a user that is not logged in)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would really like to avoid having the user click a button

FB.login without user interaction -> blocked popup

> prefer if within Page Tab iframe

The Auth dialog won’t work inside an iframe, it’s *designed* that way.

If the automatic call of the login dialog is your most important requirement – then use JavaScript to redirect to the Auth dialog URL, and redirect back to your page/app Facebook address afterwards. See section “Client-side authentication without the JS SDK” here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/client-side/

Comment: Thanks @cbroe. Yeah, was trying to use FB JS SDK as per all the recommendations and trying to avoid server-side flow.